# LSItemContentTypes does not work

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quicklook, uti

I'm trying to add a Quick Look plugin to my app, and for this to work I have to work with the devilish UTI system.

My app is a viewer of files with the .myext extension.

The relevant part of my info.plist looks like this:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>myext</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>Icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Description</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array/>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
        <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
        <string>Document</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

If I try to add a (custom) UTI identifier (com.myapp.myext) to LSItemContentTypes, my app can no longer select any file in its open dialog. Adding exported UTIs does not seem to have any effect. Running mdls on a .myext file return kMDItemContentType = "some.old.identifier", a UTI type which my app used to have when I tried doing the same thing months ago, and no longer appears in lsregister -dump. qlmanage -d 4 shows it has a dyn.xxxxxxx UTI idenitifer.

What do I have to do so both mdls and qlmanage recognize my files as com.myapp.myext?

Extra credit: How and why does mdls categorize .myext files (even newly created ones) as "some.old.identifier", even though it doesn't exist anymore, and even after lsregister -kill? How can I fix this?

Comment: If you haven't already, try logging out and back in to clear any in-memory caches that agents may hold. Also try all of the following: add an exported UTI; add that to `LSItemContentTypes`; use `lsregister` to force a scan of the built app; select a .myext file in Finder; Get Info; in the "Open with:" section of the Info window, choose the newly-built app; click Change All and confirm. What do `mdls` and `qlmanage` report after that?

Comment: Logging out and back and adding an exported UTI did make qlmanage use the correct UTI (which is good enough for my Quick Look plugin). mdls still shows that old UTI, for some reason though.